# php connecting to mysql doesnt work (raspberry pi 3 / apache2)

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi, apache2, mysql-connect

So i have this simple website for my family but somehow it doesnt work anymore  since i moved it to my raspberry pi. It worked perfectly fine on my PC using xampp though.
i have this code right at the beginning of the document:

```
 $msqlUser="root";
 $msqlpw="--PASSWORD--";
 $db = mysql_connect("localhost",$msqlUser,$msqlpw,"db");
```

when i try to open the website from my computer it just says
"This website doesnt work. --my raspberrys ip-- cannot process this request at the moment". Also there is no output from the console.

But if i comment out the line starting with $db it shows me the website normally but the mysql operations dont work of course. (Im only doing anything with mysql as soon as you press a button. If I do so i get the same error as before)

The only thing that should be different to when the site was running on my computer is that i now need to enter a port after the ip adress but i dont know wether that makes a difference

Comment: I would bet you are using a PHP version higher that PHP7. So what version of PHP are you using

Comment: Alternatively fix the connection parameters, you are missing a quote in `mysql_connect("localhost,$msqlUser,$msqlpw,"db");` try `mysql_connect("localhost",$msqlUser,$msqlpw,"db");`

Comment: THEN EDIT YOUR QUESTION AND FIX THE MISTAKE

Comment: im using php version 5.6.38

Answer (score 0):

What's the syntax you're using for the port? Are you using "localhost:port" ?

Comment: i open the website from my computer so im using 192.168.178.137:420